# iOS CocoaPod that uses a separately distributed framework

Tags: ios, xcode, cocoapods, podspec

My project involves creating a CocoaPod for public distribution that wraps functionality of a separate framework. The end-user project implements our wrapper and we deal with the complex system underneath. This means that our Pod references that separate framework but the end-user project does not.

I have had trouble working out how to automate the set up of the separate framework from within the podspec file. As it stands now, any time we run `pod install` we must add the framework to the Pod target for the methods to be correctly referenced. This may become a problem for other clients that use our Pod.

Is there a way to use the podspec settings to add a `.framework` file to the overall project?

Comment: Can you package that framework as a pod and declare it as a dependency for your pod?

Comment: Have you looked into declaring your framework as a `vendored_framework`? See http://guides.cocoapods.org/syntax/podspec.html#vendored_frameworks

Comment: @Paulw Hmm, interesting option. I'll look into it.

Comment: @Gereon I looked at that option many times but couldn't get it to do what I wanted. I'll try it again.